# Show $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z[x]$ has infinitely many prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I believe $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z[x]$ has infinitely many prime ideals but I am not sure how to prove this. I know if instead of 4 I had a prime then I could use it becoming a field and hence a UFD to get the same proof for prime numbers. I am unsure if this can be applied in some way.

Comment: If you know how to do it with a field, why not mod out by $(2)$ and then lift the ideals? The correspondence theorem maps maximal ideals to maximal ideals and prime ideals to prime ideals.

Comment: In particular, the prime ideals of $\mathbb F_2[x]$ correspond to a subset of the prime ideals of $\mathbb Z/4[x]$, i.e., those containing $2$.